# How to I get the body text of a Response object returned by the fetch API in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, fetch-api, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I'm trying to use the Github Gist API to get a list of all of my Gists like so:

```
(ns epi.core)

(.then  (.fetch js/window "https://api.github.com/users/seisvelas/gists")
        (fn [data] (.log js/epi data)))
```

`js/epi` is just `console.log` except provided by the blogging platform I'm using (epiphany.pub).

When I call that API from curl it works fine; however, when done in cljs instead of giving me the body of the response, this gives me `[object Response]`. Does anyone know how I can get the body text of the response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
(-> (.fetch js/window "https://api.github.com/users/seisvelas/gists")
  (.then #(.json %))  ; Get JSON from the Response.body ReadableStream
  (.then #(.log js/epi %))
```

is what I'd write

From ClojureScript, a JavaScript call like `data.body()` can be invoked with

```
(.body data)
```

and a JavaScript property access like `data.body` with

```
(.-body data)
```

One of those should work in your case. However, the `fetch` API requires a bit more if you want to [get JSON from the body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), which I assume you do based on the endpoint.

If you're dealing with promise chains, you might also want to consider using `->` (thread-first) so it reads top to bottom.

See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/pesterhazy/74dd6dc1246f47eb2b9cd48a1eafe649) for more about threading promise chains.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library wrapping js fetch API called [lamdaisland.fetch](https://github.com/lambdaisland/fetch). This library uses transit as default encoding format, so you need to specify accept format when working with github API.

This library contains `kitchen-async.promise` as its dependency, so you can require the kitchen-async.promise in your ClojureScript source code.

```
(ns fetch.demo.core
  (:require [kitchen-async.promise :as p]
            [lambdaisland.fetch :as fetch]))

(p/try
  (p/let [resp (fetch/get
                "https://api.github.com/users/seisvelas/gists"
                {:accept :json
                 :content-type :json})]
    (prn (:body resp)))
  (p/catch :default e
     ;; log your exception here
    (prn :error e)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like .fetch returns a Response object, and you need to get the attribute `body` from it for the body. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Something like `(.body data)`